# Adding ga:adMatchedQuery breaks API request

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a script that imports data from Google Analytics to my BI. It was working for years. Recently it stopped working.

After investigation, it turns out that removing ga:adMatchedQuery from dimensions solves the issue.

I checked changelogs (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/changelog?hl=en, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/changelog?hl=en, etc.), and do not see any deprecation notices. Are there?

Nevertheless, are there any alternative way of getting visitor's search term for my adds in Google API?

Update:
Further investigation showed that I can make a request if adMatchedQuery is the only dimension. Adding the second dimension (for example, my custom dimention or ga:hour) breaks the request.

For example:

`https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2022-09-01&end-date=2022-09-08&metrics=ga%3AgoalCompletionsAll&dimensions=ga%3Asource%2Cga%3Amedium%2Cga%3AadKeywordMatchType%2Cga%3AadMatchedQuery%2Cga%3Acountry%2Cga%3Adate%2Cga%3Ahour&sort=-ga%3AgoalCompletionsAll%2C-ga%3Adate&ids=ANALYTICS_ID` produces empty set.

`https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2022-09-01&end-date=2022-09-08&metrics=ga%3AgoalCompletionsAll&dimensions=ga%3Asource%2Cga%3Amedium%2Cga%3AadKeywordMatchType%2Cga%3AadMatchedQuery%2Cga%3Acountry%2Cga%3Adate%2C&sort=-ga%3AgoalCompletionsAll%2C-ga%3Adate&ids=ANALYTICS_ID` gives me results.

The only difference is that I removed ga:hour from the list of dimensions in the second link.

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: I have added two links to UA Query Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

Same here, it seems google made an update on Sept. 1 to restrict search queries that don't meet their higher privacy threshold, however it seems like they completely shut off search query reporting in GA. Hopefully they recognize this bug and fix it.

Check https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/178348751/search-console-report-not-showing-search-queries-for-landing-pages?hl=en&authuser=1

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue since 5 September.

I found a solution on [github](https://github.com/rxz99/analytics-issues/issues/438#issuecomment-168393192). They say you have to replace the `ga:adMatchedQuery` with `ga:keyword`.

This works for me, but not entirely sure if it is the same as `adMatchedQuery`, but the results look good though.

Hope this helps you too.

Comment: I had the same problem - coming through as (not set). "keyword" works just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and here is my solution.

Since Universal Analytics will no longer process new data in standard properties beginning July 1, 2023, Google is asking us to switch over to a Google Analytics 4 property. I guessed that it should be a way to keep us updated. So I updated my property for GA4 and I manage to access that dimension.

The `ga:adMatchedQuery` now could be found at GA4 as `firstUserGoogleAdsQuery`,`sessionGoogleAdsAdNetworkType` or `googleAdsQuery`.

I also found out that the API changed.
The service in the Google Cloud that used to bring the data was "Google Analytics Reporting API" now you need to use the service "Google Analytics Data API"

That is the quickstart Guide:
[https://developers.google.com/analytics...](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#java_1)

Metrics and Dimensions:
[https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dime...](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/)

I'm coding in Python, and that video helped me a lot:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbxIXEfl-Hs&t=2s)